# Silex Doctrine ORM Create Entity

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Всем привет, пытаюсь подключить доктрину, но не совсем понимаю правильно ли я это делаю, и как мне создавать сущности из консоли, так например, чтобы легче было создавать связь между сущостями Многие ко Многим

я уже подключила саму Доктрину :

```
//public/bootstrap/bootstrap.php

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(// Подробнее настройка DBAL тут: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'dbname' => 'test',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8'
    )
));
```

в официальной документации нет ничего на тему, как создавать сущности - https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/doctrine.html

на просторах интернета тоже найти не смогла, может кто-то знает как с этим справиться?